# Phrases or words to describe the sound a scissors makes

Tags: word-choice, phrases

What would be a description of the sound a scissors makes when its two blades come together? Some examples might be:

- "The **clipping** of fingernails."
- "The **snip** of the blades".

Words or phrases work.

Answer (score 2):

Snipping is the most common word I've seen used to describe it

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the others; *snip* is the sound used for scissors.

I just ran a Google Ngram for `"the * of the scissors"`, and 9 of the top 10 results referred to physical parts of scissors (the *blade* of the scissors, the *handle* of the scissors, the *tip* of the scissors, etc.). Only one referred to a sound – the *snip* of the scissors.

[image]

> As he took a few steps back, he heard the snip of the scissors as Mrs. Kennedy cut a lock of her husband's hair. (Source: *The Kennedy Detail: JFK's Secret Service Agents Break Their Silence*  by Gerald Blaine & Lisa McCubbin, 2010)

I also did a Google search for `"heard the * of the scissors"`, which offered a few alternatives (like *click* or *snap*), but *snip* was the overwhelming favorite.

Answer (score 1):

If you snip (cut) something with scissors, the snipping sound produced by scissors is called "snip".

A Yahoo site says that somewhat insane gave the best answer regarding the sound of scissors as follows:

"They go 'snip snip snip'....I like the sound of scissors, I don't know why though".

Answer (score 0):

Scissors make *snipping* sound. I'm in an IT company where we do make games for mobile devices. When it comes to ***download*** scissors' sound, we search for the audio clip of 'Scissors Snips'

Here is the site that offers you various sounds of scissors. [Check out the audio clips labeled 'Scissors Snip'.](http://www.soundrangers.com/index.cfm/category/486/scissor-sound-effects.cfm)

Some may also use 'Scissors cutting sound' because the instrument is used for cutting, whatever it is.

Answer (score -1):

A very gentle "sssssst" when cutting into something like a fine piece of paper or perhaps some card stock.